# Allowed characters in Python function names

Tags: python, function

Are there any other allowed characters in Python function names except alphabetical characters, numbers, and underscores? If yes, what are they?

Comment: google it: http://www.pasteur.fr/formation/infobio/python/ch02s03.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Valid characters in a python class name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120295/valid-characters-in-a-python-class-name)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the naming convention in Python for variable and function names?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159720/what-is-the-naming-convention-in-python-for-variable-and-function-names)

Comment: @danny Conventional != allowed.

Comment: @delnan you are right.

Answer (score 16):

[In Python 3 many characters are allowed](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-identifier):

```
identifier   ::=  xid_start xid_continue*
id_start     ::=  <all characters in general categories Lu, Ll, Lt, Lm, Lo, Nl, 
                   the underscore, and characters with the Other_ID_Start property>
id_continue  ::=  <all characters in id_start, plus characters in the categories 
                   Mn, Mc, Nd, Pc and others with the Other_ID_Continue property>
xid_start    ::=  <all characters in id_start whose NFKC normalization 
                   is in "id_start xid_continue*">
xid_continue ::=  <all characters in id_continue whose NFKC normalization 
                   is in "id_continue*">

The Unicode category codes mentioned above stand for:

Lu - uppercase letters
Ll - lowercase letters
Lt - titlecase letters
Lm - modifier letters
Lo - other letters
Nl - letter numbers
Mn - nonspacing marks
Mc - spacing combining marks
Nd - decimal numbers
Pc - connector punctuations
Other_ID_Start - explicit list of characters in PropList.txt 
                 to support backwards compatibility
Other_ID_Continue - likewise
```

The complete list of every character can be found on [Unicode.org](https://www.unicode.org/Public/13.0.0/ucd/DerivedCoreProperties.txt).

---

In Python 2.x it was limited to just letters, numbers, and underscore. From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-identifier):

```
identifier ::=  (letter|"_") (letter | digit | "_")*
letter     ::=  lowercase | uppercase
lowercase  ::=  "a"..."z"
uppercase  ::=  "A"..."Z"
digit      ::=  "0"..."9"
```

Comment: Point to any version of the Python 3.x docs, and the answer is yes :) eg: http://docs.python.org/3.2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers

Comment: @JonClements D'oh! Edited.