# Regular Expression: Simple Syntax Highlighting (Python)

Tags: python, regex, syntax-highlighting

I have been struggling with creating a regular expression that will differentiate between an object definition and calling that object in Python. The purpose is syntax highlighting.

This is the situation which needs to be resolved: (numbers denote line)

```
0    def otherfunc(vars...):
1        pass
2
3    otherfunc(vars...)
```

I am interested in matching the name of the object, but not if preceded anywhere by def in the same line. The result on the above code should be:

"otherfunc", line: 3

Is regular expressions capable of doing something like this?

EDIT: I am only concerned with scanning/searching a single line at a time.

Comment: Yes, to an extent... however if you want it to *not* match within multiline strings and such, then it becomes much harder...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I am only concerned with scanning a single line at a time. I shall edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: How would you determine if it is a function?  A class is callable, and so are some other objects.  Do you include `lambda`s in this?

Comment: @cdarke That is a good point. It is imprecise to call it a function. I shall edit my question to reflect this.

Comment: Does this really need to be implemented solely with a regular expression? If you're unfamiliar with regular expressions, sometimes a more straight-forward approach will do. First, search for the thing you're searching for with a simple regular expression, and then iterate over the results to throw out things you don't care about.

Answer (score 0):

You could use negative lookbehind. This matches an atom that is not preceded by an atom.  So in your case your looking for `otherfunc` which is not preceded by `"def"`

I'm use PCRE regex here.

```
(?<!def\s)otherfunc
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Richards answer, however I would also take into considerarion the valid function name characters of phyton and intendation. So this is what I came up with:

```
(?<!(def\s))(?<=^|\s)[a-zA-Z_][\w_]*(?=\()
```

See this [working sample on Rexex101](https://regex101.com/r/aXJHrY/2)

### Explanation

Matches valid [python function names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482730/allowed-characters-in-python-function-names) if

1. `(?<!(def\s))` they are not following a `def` and a whitespace **and**
2. `(?<=^|\s)` are either at the beginning of a line, or following a whitespace (this is the closest you get, since lookbehinds dont support wildcard specifiers) **and**
3. are followed by a opening bracket (`(`)

Note that I am not an phyton dev, so for the sake of simplicity `[a-zA-Z_][\w_]*` matches valid phyton 2.x function names, you can extend this part of the expression to phyton 3.x which I have no clue of ;)