# Is there a difference between these two list comprehensions or a bug?

Tags: python, list, emacs, list-comprehension

I have two lists that I am trying to manipulate via a list comprehension in Python. I am doing this in the pdb debugger inside Emacs (just in case this is the cause of the problem :-). Both lists are derived from data structures in my script, but at the point where I'm trying to use them, I've parsed them to lists. Here is my output in pdb, along with a little test up front to show what I think should work (but doesn't ?):

```
(Pdb) l1 = [100, 200, 300]
(Pdb) l2 = [1,2,3]
(Pdb) [x+y for x in l2 for y in l1]
[101, 201, 301, 102, 202, 302, 103, 203, 303]
(Pdb) data_ids = [int(i['Transaction ID']) for i in data]
(Pdb) data_ids[0]
2669299
(Pdb) len(data_ids)
707
(Pdb) type(data_ids)
<class 'list'>
(Pdb) ovr_trans_ids = [i['ovr_trans_no'] for i in overrides]
(Pdb) ovr_trans_ids[0]
2643831
(Pdb) len(ovr_trans_ids)
87
(Pdb) type(ovr_trans_ids)
<class 'list'>
(Pdb) [x+y for x in data_ids for y in ovr_trans_ids]
*** NameError: name 'ovr_trans_ids' is not defined
```

These two list comprehensions -- the first using the two simple lists l1 and l2 that I created and the second using the two lists derived from my data -- appear to me be structurally identical. Is anyone able to tell me why in the second one ovr_trans_ids is throwing a NameError? You can see in the previous statements that it exists, is a list, and has members. Also double-checked the two simple lists:

```
(Pdb) type(l1)
<class 'list'>
(Pdb) type(l2)
<class 'list'>
(Pdb)
```

Am I missing something really fundamental here? Or weird and esoteric?

And just in case, here are the two lists' data, just to prove there's nothing weird in them:

```
(Pdb) [i for i in data_ids]
[2669299, 2669471, 2669473, 2669148, 2669154, 2669135, 2669048, 2669121, 2669146, 2669147, 2669377, 2669379, 2669581, 2669582, 2669580, 2669152, 2669443, 2669381, 2669036, 2669478, 2669481, 2669633, 2669098, 2669099, 2669158, 2669160, 2669170, 2669175, 2669180, 2669182, 2669386, 2669387, 2669274, 2669484, 2669486, 2669306, 2658733, 2658733, 2658735, 2658735, 2658739, 2658739, 2669410, 2669414, 2669199, 2669201, 2669208, 2669212, 2669211, 2669215, 2669217, 2669218, 2669283, 2669284, 2669285, 2669219, 2669220, 2669221, 2669222, 2669223, 2669225, 2669226, 2669228, 2669278, 2669279, 2669280, 2669282, 2669230, 2669234, 2669231, 2669240, 2669242, 2669249, 2669253, 2669256, 2669259, 2669260, 2669261, 2669262, 2669263, 2669266, 2669268, 2669269, 2669271, 2669272, 2669273, 2669275, 2669276, 2669277, 2669349, 2669350, 2669358, 2669359, 2669360, 2669361, 2669362, 2669366, 2669368, 2669369, 2669370, 2669372, 2669138, 2669141, 2669034, 2669035, 2669331, 2669332, 2669333, 2669334, 2669337, 2669338, 2669320, 2669325, 2669339, 2669340, 2669335, 2669207, 2669184, 2669179, 2669569, 2669232, 2669235, 2669173, 2669239, 2669290, 2669156, 2669188, 2669245, 2669191, 2669060, 2669536, 2669427, 2669102, 2669103, 2669108, 2669109, 2669110, 2669437, 2669437, 2669470, 2669431, 2669040, 2669041, 2669380, 2669596, 2669128, 2669137, 2669139, 2669140, 2669142, 2669136, 2664274, 2664274, 2664275, 2664275, 2664276, 2664276, 2668318, 2668318, 2669515, 2669517, 2669528, 2669512, 2669144, 2669143, 2669590, 2669165, 2669145, 2246915, 2246915, 2669286, 2669287, 2669289, 2669288, 2669593, 2669373, 2669382, 2669394, 2669389, 2669389, 2669398, 2669565, 2669033, 2669032, 2669475, 2669472, 2669629, 2669627, 2669088, 2669063, 2669063, 2669086, 2669122, 2669293, 2669295, 2669096, 2669167, 2669167, 2669171, 2669171, 2669168, 2669168, 2669451, 2669453, 2669456, 2669448, 2669458, 2669461, 2669462, 2669465, 2669169, 2669498, 2669500, 2669501, 2669439, 2669429, 2669134, 2669104, 2669105, 2669464, 2669509, 2669510, 2669511, 2513164, 2513164, 2669095, 2669068, 2669068, 2669095, 2669095, 2513166, 2669064, 2669064, 2513164, 2513166, 2360653, 2360653, 2360653, 2513161, 2513161, 2669085, 2669085, 2360586, 2360586, 2513162, 2513162, 2669495, 2669506, 2669476, 2669488, 2669441, 2669483, 2669497, 2669491, 2669503, 2669050, 2669296, 2669124, 2669600, 2669601, 2669395, 2669395, 2669401, 2669402, 2669294, 2669130, 2669131, 2669514, 2669066, 2669067, 2669069, 2669070, 2669071, 2669072, 2669074, 2669075, 2669076, 2669077, 2669078, 2669150, 2669123, 2669357, 2669357, 2669586, 2669589, 2669125, 2669106, 2669107, 2669236, 2669237, 2669238, 2669241, 2669246, 2669243, 2669250, 2669251, 2669255, 2669257, 2669244, 2669258, 2669037, 2669200, 2669202, 2669203, 2669204, 2669206, 2669628, 2669164, 2669210, 2669213, 2669149, 1480829, 1480829, 2668219, 2668219, 2669162, 2669205, 2669209, 2669153, 2669155, 2548599, 2548604, 2607298, 2548599, 2548604, 2607298, 2669133, 2669126, 2669489, 2669490, 2669455, 2669467, 2669436, 2669436, 2669440, 2669440, 2669479, 2669468, 2669468, 2669482, 2669383, 2669388, 2669384, 2669385, 2669151, 2444259, 2444259, 2444259, 2444259, 2662671, 2662671, 2669046, 2669045, 2669047, 2669229, 2669233, 2669267, 2669270, 2669044, 2669264, 2669038, 2669039, 2669591, 2669631, 2669630, 2669626, 2669624, 2669625, 2669610, 2669607, 2669605, 2669606, 2669603, 2669602, 2669192, 2669390, 2669391, 2669392, 2669393, 2669396, 2669397, 2669399, 2669400, 2669404, 2669405, 2669406, 2669408, 2669409, 2669411, 2669412, 2669413, 2669415, 2669416, 2669417, 2669418, 2669419, 2669420, 2669421, 2669422, 2669423, 2669424, 2669425, 2669426, 2669428, 2669430, 2669432, 2669433, 2669434, 2669438, 2669187, 2669595, 2669597, 2669598, 2669592, 2669594, 2669574, 2669575, 2669575, 2669585, 2669588, 2664826, 2664826, 2669355, 2669291, 2669292, 2669614, 2669615, 2669446, 2669079, 2669091, 2669093, 2669051, 2669058, 2669059, 2669363, 2669492, 2669493, 2669494, 2669435, 2669496, 2669281, 2669248, 2669254, 2669224, 2669364, 2669365, 2669367, 2669371, 2669341, 2669342, 2669344, 2669347, 2669348, 2669351, 2669353, 2669053, 2669054, 2669055, 2669057, 2473297, 2473297, 2473297, 2473297, 2669336, 2669056, 2669062, 2669062, 2669065, 2669065, 2669065, 2669513, 2669527, 2669531, 2669531, 2669552, 2669553, 2669214, 2669161, 2669119, 2669127, 2669469, 2669314, 2669321, 2669326, 2669117, 2669118, 2669120, 2669599, 2669445, 2669297, 2669298, 2669300, 2669302, 2669305, 2669307, 2669459, 2669463, 2669195, 2669197, 2669193, 2669194, 2669176, 2669185, 2669172, 2669252, 2669522, 2669544, 2669546, 2669549, 2669578, 2669579, 2669587, 2669576, 2669584, 2669583, 2669374, 2669375, 2669634, 2669577, 2669129, 2669635, 2669356, 2669356, 2669555, 2669556, 2669558, 2669061, 2669301, 2669112, 2669113, 2669504, 2669505, 2669507, 2669508, 2669442, 2669159, 2669447, 2669449, 2669450, 2669452, 2669454, 2669457, 2669460, 2669444, 2668514, 2668514, 2668533, 2668533, 2668528, 2668528, 2668539, 2668539, 2668541, 2668541, 2668543, 2668543, 2668551, 2668551, 2668557, 2668557, 2668560, 2668560, 2668562, 2668562, 2668571, 2668571, 2669216, 2669378, 2669477, 2669480, 2669485, 2669354, 2499080, 2499080, 2669043, 2669042, 2669376, 2669466, 2669407, 2669474, 2669311, 2669311, 2669343, 2669318, 2669318, 2669345, 2669346, 2669352, 2669265, 2669265, 2669196, 2669247, 2669190, 2669177, 2669609, 2669621, 2669620, 2669618, 2669616, 2669617, 2669608, 2669613, 2669611, 2669612, 2669623, 2669622, 2669521, 2669534, 2669541, 2669557, 2669559, 2669502, 2669550, 2669561, 2669563, 2669563, 2669551, 2669554, 2669516, 2669518, 2669519, 2669520, 2669523, 2669524, 2669525, 2669526, 2669529, 2669530, 2669532, 2669533, 2669535, 2669537, 2669538, 2669539, 2669540, 2669542, 2669543, 2669545, 2669547, 2669548, 2669604, 2669309, 2669310, 2669312, 2669313, 2669315, 2669316, 2669317, 2669319, 2669322, 2669323, 2669324, 2669327, 2669328, 2669329, 2669330, 2669049, 2669308, 2669087, 2669089, 2669090, 2669084, 2669092, 2669082, 2669094, 2669101, 2669097, 2669100, 2669487, 2669304, 2669081, 2669080, 2669083, 2669163, 2669166, 2669111, 2669114, 2669560, 2669562, 2669115, 2669116, 2669632, 2669572, 2669499, 2669619, 2669403, 2669566, 2669567, 2669564, 2669073, 2669052, 2669303, 2669568, 2669570, 2669571, 2669573, 2669174, 2669174, 2669181, 2669178, 2669183, 2669198, 2669157, 2669132, 2669227, 2669186, 2669189]

(Pdb) [i for i in ovr_trans_ids]
[2643831, 2643829, 2643833, 2643834, 2643827, 2643379, 2643011, 2643014, 2643016, 2643004, 2643019, 2643020, 2643023, 2643022, 2643026, 2643038, 2643043, 2643032, 2643036, 2642102, 2640722, 2642066, 2641792, 2641761, 2641925, 2641762, 2641783, 1625044, 1642214, 1690503, 1744960, 1758411, 1762104, 1818109, 1876448, 1927152, 1978012, 1992422, 1992863, 2036783, 2090400, 2134492, 2176780, 2187001, 2193071, 2229660, 2285643, 2329190, 2368459, 2381546, 2383473, 2423428, 2479972, 2522333, 2564597, 2577734, 2578759, 2614252, 2580012, 2114716, 2125297, 2644874, 2644883, 2644884, 2644887, 2644888, 2644889, 2644618, 2647702, 2652217, 2652221, 2652999, 2669309, 2669310, 2669312, 2669313, 2669315, 2669316, 2669317, 2669319, 2669322, 2669323, 2669324, 2669327, 2669328, 2669329, 2669330]
```

Comment: My first guess is that there is some non-printing character in your final line's version of "ovr_trans_ids".  Try doing up-arrow back to the first list comprehension.  Run it again to get your proof-of-concept.  Then cut & paste the "ovr_trans_ids" name from one of your middle commands, inserting it as the "y" list in the double comprehension (keep x in l2 for now).  I'm hopeful that will resolve the mystery.

Comment: @Prune - I don't see how that could be the problem, as such characters can't be part of a [valid Python variable name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120295/valid-characters-in-a-python-class-name).

Comment: Please post a shorter example, including usable values for `data` and `overrides`, that reproduce the problem and we can try to run.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem using your data and Python 2.7.9

Comment: Thanks everyone for the assistance. As it turns out, this looks like some kind of ephemeral bug in pdb inside Emacs. Unfortunately don't have the time to chase it down, but thanks for the confirmation that I wasn't missing something really basic.