# Extract variables using python regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Input file contains following lines:

```
a=b*c;
d=a+2;
c=0;
b=a;
```

Now for each line I want to extract variables that has been used.For example, for line 1, the output should be `[a,b,c]`.Currently I am doing as follows :

```
var=[a,b,c,d]     # list of variables
for line in file_ptr :
    if '=' in line :
        temp=line.split('=') :
        ans=list(temp[0])
        if '+' in temp[1] :
             # do something
        elif '*' in temp[1] :
             # do something
        else :
             # single variable as line 4  OR constant as line 3
```

Is it possible to do this using regex?

**EDIT:**

Expected output for above file :

```
[a,b,c]
[d,a]
[c]
[a,b]
```

Comment: How is the question too broad ?

Comment: What output would you expect from the input you've specified?

Comment: @Robᵩ I have added them in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `re.findall()` with whatever pattern matches variable names in the example's programming language. Assuming a typical language, this might work for you:

```
import re

lines = '''a=b*c;
d=a+2;
c=0;
b=a;'''

for line in lines.splitlines():
    print re.findall('[_a-z][_a-z0-9]*', line, re.I)
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24541431/2564301) contains the explanation @AkaSh is looking for. Python's variable names are case sensitive, so it needs the Ignore Case flag (or, alternatively, just a few `A-Z`s). I'd throw in a few `\b` for consistency, though.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use some shorter pattern for matching variable names:

```
import re
strs = ['a=b*c;', 'd=a+2;', 'c=0;', 'b=a;']
print([re.findall(r'[_a-z]\w*', x, re.I) for x in strs])
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/Suj0Cj)

Pattern matches:

- `[_a-z]` - a `_` or an ASCII letter (any upper or lowercase due to the case insensitive modifier use `re.I`)
- `\w*` - 0 or more alphanumeric or underscore characters.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kL2kU9/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the variables, then do this:

```
answer = []
for line in file_ptr :
    temp = []
    for char in line:
        if char.isalpha():
            temp.append(char)
    answer.append(temp)
```

A word of caution though: this would work only with variables that are exactly 1 character in length. More details about `isalpha()` can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) or [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isalpha.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're after, but you can do something like this:

```
re.split(r'[^\w]', line)
```

to give a list of the alphabetic characters in the line:

```
>>> re.split(r'[^\w]', 'a=b*c;')
['a', 'b', 'c', '']
```

Comment: `a`, `b`, `c` are variables.These are elements of list `var`

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: This fails on the examples with digits; digits are also 'word characters' and so would be included. It can trivially be fixed, though, especially if Python's `re` supports `[[:alpha:]]`. However, for 'any' variable name, you need a different expression for just the first character and all next ones, because `a0` is a valid variable name.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did :

```
l=re.split(r'[^A-Za-z]', 'a=b*2;')
l=filter(None,l)
```