# Tkinter Button widget with .pack() as an invalid syntax

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter, widget

I am making a basic tictactoe game in tkinter, in Python 3.5.3 but I ran into an error saying .pack() was an invalid syntax. Code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
turn = X
1 = Button(root, command=Pressed)
1.pack()
def Pressed():
    pass
root.geometry('900x900')
root.mainloop()
```

Please could someone give me an answer.

Comment: Here is the grammar of the valid identifiers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10120327/7051394

Comment: Why can't variable names start with numbers? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342152/why-cant-variable-names-start-with-numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning an invalid variable name for your button.
Try rewrite

```
1 = Button(root, command=Pressed)
1.pack()
```

To something like:

```
button_1 = Button(root, command=Pressed)
button_1.pack()
```

Note on variable names:

- Must begin with a letter (a - z, A - B) or underscore (_)
- Other characters can be letters, numbers or _
- Case Sensitive
- Can be any (reasonable) length
- There are some reserved words which you cannot use as a variable name
  because Python uses them for other things.

Comment: It solves the pack problem but now it says I haven't defined Pressed()

Comment: Yeah, because you assign `Pressed` before it's declared so you should put the `def Pressed()` block before `button_1 = Button(...` and then it should work.