# Django models naming convention

Tags: python, django, django-models

Can any one please look at the below piece of code to create table/class in models.py. I need these column names as I plan to auto upload the table values via excel on external location automatically. Hence dont want to change the column names. I have tried adding single quotes arround the column names with special characters.

Could you please help me create the below table/class. Currently it is indicating syntax error. I have got another class called Number for different app under the same project. Not sure if that is an issue.

```py
from django.db import models


class Errors(models.Model):

    'S/O#' = models.IntegerField(max_length=10)

    Line Number = models.IntegerField()

    'S/O' Type = models.CharField(max_length=5)

    Error Detail = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    Comments = models.TextField()

    'Incident#' = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    Assigned To = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    Issue Status = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    Action = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't think that has anything to do with Django. Please refer to Python's documentation to find out what characters are acceptable as names

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Valid characters in a python class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120295/valid-characters-in-a-python-class-name)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Pynchia. I have tried single and double quotes which was suggested for other special characters. Secondly for testing purpose I have added underscore to isolate acceptable names but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do that due to the restrictions of the python language.

You could perhaps look at overriding the default generated table and/or field name instead.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.db_column
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#table-names

So instead of this:

```
'S/O#' = models.IntegerField(max_length=10)  # not a valid field name
```

Try something like this:

```
so_number = models.IntegerField(max_length=10, db_column='S/O#)
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. db_column attribute has cleared the error. I have now used it for all the column names with special characters and not allowed names. I will now work on my auto upload.

Answer (score 1):

Just use "/" -> "_" and "#" -> "N".