# How to check if a class name is valid in Python

Tags: python-3.x, dynamic

[I did find this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120295/valid-characters-in-a-python-class-name), but he is trying to sanitize the name, I just want to know if it's valid or not. And a regex solution doesn't fit my needs cause is a fragile solution and specifications may change and/or escape some edgy cases.

Answer (score 1):

A maintainable solution for me is build a class and check it with AST. If the language move forward, the package should move forward as well.

```
import ast
def is_valid_class_name(name):
    class_definition = f'class {name}: pass'
    try:
        ast.parse(class_definition)
    except Exception as e:
        return False
    return True
```

That's it.

The same trick could be applied to `variable name`, `assignment`, whatever you want to check if is valid in python. Using a template ( which in this case is `class NAMEOFCLASS: pass')`